# Estoy intentando compilar un programa en c que utiliza la función EVP_aes_128_cbc

Tags: c

[image: este es el error que obtengo, pese a haber instalado las librerias que hacen falta y enlazarlas]

No se si es un problema al enlazar, o que directamente no tengo bien instaladas las librerias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Soy daltónico y no veo bien el color verde ¿podrías pegar el texto en lugar de una imagen?